# How to install extension/widget via composer in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, ckeditor, composer-php, yii-extensions

I newbie in yii2. 
i try to install extention Ckeditor. 
Scenario :

1. I used xampp.
2. my folder name in htdocs is 'bic'

=== install via composer =================

```
c:\xampp\php>composer require 2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget
```

successfully to install, but i can't still used. and in my

## bic\yiisoft\vendor i can't find 2amigos folder.

i write in my view

```
use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor;
<?= $form->field($model, 'text')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
`options` => [`rows` => 6],
`preset` => `basic`
]) ?>
```

I've got error Class `dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor` not found.

So, i think, i was wrong to install extensions via composer. Please give me advice.

Comment: Hi.you should be go here in commad line c->xampp->htdocs->bic and then run your command

Comment: Hi, if i go in c:\xampp\htdocs\bic>composer require 2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget    i've got error. 'php.exe' is not recognized

Comment: add your php.exe to your system variables, on you computer right click properties->Advanced System Setting->Environtment variabels. in text area System variable, at 'PATH' add your 'php.exe' path into it. Then download composer.phar to your root project then execute 'php omposer.phar require 2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your `composer.json` file to include something like?:

```
"require": {
    ...
  "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget" : "2.0",
    ...
}
```

Anyway you are using backticks instead of single quotes in options and missing one in `'preset' => 'basic`... Is it a typo?

Comment: Hi Antonio, Still not run... i think, i wrong place to install. so i found folder 2amigos in /xampp/php/vendor not in my bic folder.